# PostgreSQL how to use with as

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

Anybody know why this isn't working? I'm getting: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "most_recent"

```
with most_recent as (SELECT MAX(public."Master_playlist".updated_at)
FROM public."Master_playlist")
SELECT * from public."Playlist"
JOIN public."Master_playlist_playlist" on public."Playlist".id = public."Master_playlist_playlist".playlist_id
JOIN public."Master_playlist" on public."Master_playlist_playlist".master_playlist_id = public."Master_playlist".id
WHERE public."Master_playlist".updated_at = most_recent;
```

Supposed to be getting the most recent date from Master_playlist and then using that to select a Master_playlist to join the inner query with

Thanks! HM

Answer (score 2):

The `with` clause creates a derived table, which you need select from, using a `join` or a subquery. You also need to alias the column so you can refer to it afterwards, as in:

```
with most_recent as (
    SELECT MAX(updated_at) max_updated_at
    FROM public."Master_playlist"
)
SELECT * 
from public."Playlist"
JOIN public."Master_playlist_playlist" 
    on public."Playlist".id = public."Master_playlist_playlist".playlist_id
JOIN public."Master_playlist" 
    on public."Master_playlist_playlist".master_playlist_id = public."Master_playlist".id
WHERE public."Master_playlist".updated_at = (SELECT max_updated_at FROM most_recent)
```

But here, it looks like it is simpler to use a row-limiting query:

```
select ...
from (
    select *
    from public."Master_playlist"
    order by updated_at desc
    limit 1
) mp
inner join public."Master_playlist_playlist" mpp
    on mpp.master_playlist_id = mp.id
inner join public."Playlist" p
    on p.id = mpp.playlist_id
```